# If you store info in the settings file via an iPad is it accessible?

Tags: xcode, ipad

If you store info in the settings file via an iPad is it accessible?

Is this data secure, can other applications see it?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

/*Unsave Username*/

[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"secret_data1"]
forKey:@"key1"];

[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"secret_data2"]
forKey:@"key2"];
```

Is that data secure? Can users access this? Can an application? How secure is this?

Comment: You need to define what "secure" means for you. It is definitely possible to get that data out under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an encryption method to make it more secure.

Comment: If it's secure enough to warrant encryption, you should just stuff it in the Keychain.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly secure. This data is synced to the computer when the iPad backs up, and it's also trivially accessed on a jailbroken device. If you have any secure data you should be using the [Keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) instead.